# unknown field error when deploying to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-k8-web-deployment
  labels:
    app: django-k8-web-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 3

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-k8-web-deployment

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-k8-web-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django-k8s-web
          image: registry.digitalocean.com/chrisocean/django-k8s-web:latest
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
              name: django-k8s-web-prod-env
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "8001"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: oceandev
```

the above yaml file above is what I want to apply in kubernetes. I ran the folowing command on my terminal

```bash
kubectl apply -f k8s/apps/django-k8s-web.yaml
```

then I go the following error on the terminal

```bash
kubectl apply -f k8s/apps/django-k8s-web.yaml
service/django-k8-web-service unchanged
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "k8s/apps/django-k8s-web.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[0].name"
```

who knows how to resolve the issue?

I wanted it to apply the changes in the yaml file but it is not working.When I ran the following command

```bash
kubectl get pods
```

the STATUS of the pod is pending

Comment: Under `envFrom:`, `name:` needs to be indented one step more, to be a child of `secretRef:`.

Answer (score 7):

This is issue with indentation.

Here is proper `deployment` definition

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-k8-web-deployment
  labels:
    app: django-k8-web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-k8-web-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-k8-web-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: django-k8s-web
        image: registry.digitalocean.com/chrisocean/django-k8s-web:latest
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: django-k8s-web-prod-env
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8001"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: oceandev
```